# Split string on non consecutive capital letters

Tags: python, regex, string, split, capitalization

I'm trying to split a string by capital letter BUT i don't want to split two consecutive capital letters.

So for now I'm doing this:

```
my_string == "TTestStringAA"
re.findall('[a-zA-Z][^A-Z]*', my_string)
>>> ['T', 'Test', 'String', 'A', 'A']
```

But the output that I'm looking for is:

```
>>> ['TTest', 'String', 'AA']
```

There is a clean and simple solution to this problem?

Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `[A-Z]+[a-z]*` meets your requirements:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Z]+[a-z]*', my_string)
['TTest', 'String', 'AA']
```

Comment: This worked for me but I did some little changes because I found that this solution didn't preserve the lower letters at the start and numbers were not correctly split so finally this was the solution I came up with: r'[A-Z0-9]*[a-z]*'

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will return the correct result.

```
[a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z]*|[a-z]+$
```

Test Cases:

```
tests = ['a', 'A', 'aa', 'Aa' 'AaAaAAAaAa', 'aTTestStringAA']
regex = re.compile(r'[a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z]*|[a-z]+$')
for test in tests:
    print('{} => {}'.format(test, re.findall(regex, test)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.split` with

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Ojh7G0/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

[Python code](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9ZNBtP//2fmFuQXlSgUpXIVJJaUpBblKdgqFClp2NvYRifqVsVqatjbRjvqRsVqKnGVpBaXAGWVQkKAjOCSosy8dEdHJa4CIKNEoyhVr7ggJ7NEA2qMjgJIuabm//8A):

```
import re
pattern = r"(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])"
test = "TTestStringAA"
print(re.split(pattern, test))
```

Results:

```
['TTest', 'String', 'AA']
```